# what is the difference between ARM7 and ARM7s

Tags: ios, xcode, arm

I realized that xcode 4.5 comes with ARM7 and ARM7s in valid architectures. I got a link error. After sometime digging, I removed arm7s and things start to work again.

I need to understand what is ARM7s, I am assuming this is related to iPhone5?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that ARM **v** 7 is very different from ARM7.

Comment: See [Apple A6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A6) for brief information on the tweaked instruction set of ARMv7s.

Comment: See [Apple A5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A5) for information on Cortex-A9 and ARMv7 instruction set.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes you are right about armv7s is about the iPhone 5. Here some summary info I found on the web:

- ARMv6 ISA (used by the ARM11 core in the iPhone 2G and iPhone 3G)
- ARMv7 (used by modern ARM cores, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4 and 4S)
- ARMv7s (new A6 SoC for iPhone 5).

Ref: [There](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6292/iphone-5-a6-not-a15-custom-core) and [there](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Armv7).

Comment: The second link is now dead; it is bad to post links with no info extracted from them.